# create array from currentYear back to 2022

Tags: javascript

Let's say we have this:

`const currentYear = 2026`

and we want to create an array back to 2022 like:
 `[2026, 2025, 2024, 2023, 2022]`

I have this code right now but it doesn't work as expected:

```js
const currentYear = 2026


const newArray = [currentYear].map(i => {
  const year = i - 1;
  if(year >= 2022) return year
});

console.log([currentYear, ...newArray])
```

Comment: `Array.from({ length: 5}, (_, i) => currentYear - i)`

Comment: If you have start and end years as parameters, `const start = 2026, end = 2022`, then `Array.from({ length: start-end+1 }, (_, i) => start - i)`

Comment: `const years = Array.from({ length: 5 }, (_, i) => currentYear - i);`

Answer (score 0):

The map function takes a callback function and applies that function to each element in the array. It then returns a new array containing the result for each element.

For example, if you wanted to increase every value in an array by 1 you could do this:

```
const numbers = [1, 2, 3];

const increasedNumbers = numbers.map(number => number + 1);
//increasedNumbers would hold [2,3,4]
```

It seems you want to make an array of numbers that start at 1 number and count backward to finish on another number. You can achieve that with a for loop like this:

```
const startYear = 2026;
const finishYear = 2022;
const years = [];

for (let i = startYear; i >= finishYear; i--) {
  years.push(i);
}

//years will hold [2026, 2025, 2024, 2023, 2022]
```